# how can i break this correlated sql->oracle statement up?

Tags: sql, oracle, correlated-subquery

```
UPDATE t1
   SET t1.language_id = (SELECT distinct(CASE WHEN NETWORK.nid = 11 
                                  THEN 10
                                  ELSE 7
                              END)
                       FROM PROFILE,
                            NETWORK
                      WHERE PROFILE.STATUS IN ('A','U','S','H','I')
                        AND PROFILE.mid = t1.mid
                        AND NETWORK.mid = t1.mid
                        AND t1.is_deleted = 'N')

   AND EXISTS( SELECT 1

              FROM PROFILE,
                   NETWORK
             WHERE PROFILE.STATUS IN ('A','U','S','H','I')
               AND PROFILE.mid = t1.mid
               AND NETWORK.mid = t1.mid
               AND t1.is_deleted = 'N');
```

It's way to slow.  Use different updates for use statements?  do one update for 10 and one for 7.

Comment: Why do you believe that breaking up the statement will improve performance?  If you have a performance issue, what is the query plan? What indexes are available?  I believe this is related to an earlier question where I posted a similar query in my answer-- in my query, I had a `WHERE EXISTS`.  As posted, your `AND EXISTS` isn't valid because there is no `WHERE` clause.  How many rows are in each table?  How many rows of `t1` are you updating?  How long does it take?  What is your performance goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query for every record in `t1` table database executes separate query on `NETWORK` and `PROFILE` tables. In reality you need to scan this tables only once.

I suggest you to use MERGE clause:

```
merge into t1
using (
  select
    network.mid,
    decode(network.nid, 11, 10, 7) language_id,
  from
    profile,
    network
  where
    profile.status in ('A','U','S','H','I')
    and
    network.mid = profile.mid
) update_set 
on
  t1.mid = update_set.mid 
  and
  t1.is_deleted = 'N'
when matched
  then update set t1.language_id = update_set.language_id
;
```

For more information look for [description in Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Check indexes and statistics on MID columns (I assumed high selectivity). 
Check execution plan. Check PQ / PDML. 
If your MID is UNIQUE column on all sides, you can change it to:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.language_id = (SELECT distinct(CASE WHEN NETWORK.nid = 11 
                              THEN 10
                              ELSE 7
                          END)
                   FROM NETWORK
                   where NETWORK.mid = t1.mid
                   )
WHERE EXIST ( SELECT 1 from NETWORK where NETWORK.mid = t1.mid )
AND EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM PROFILE where PROFILE.STATUS IN ('A','U','S','H','I')
                    AND PROFILE.mid = t1.mid )
AND t1.is_deleted = 'N'
```